# javascript function object prototype

Tags: javascript, html

Why prototype function is not called .. when image is clicket?

Html Code :--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="tt.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>This example calls a function which performs a calculation, and returns the result:</p>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <input type="image" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTcJA5J-LOj0HOP1ZMzdSQIsxwuguFdtlesHqzU15W8TXx232pFg" onclick="myFunction('Info clicked')"/>

   <script>
     var a = new myFunction();
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a.k;
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

java script :--

```
function myFunction(l) {
    this.k = "hello";
    alert(this.k);

    var t = this.temp(l);
    alert(t);


}

myFunction.prototype.temp = function(a)
{
    alert(a);

    return 10;
}
```

If i put inside html page body it works :--

```
<script>
var a = new myFunction();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a.k;
</script>
```

Comment: `myFunction` is a constructor and needs to be invoked with `new`!

Comment: Seems you are confusing [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) with [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img), input has no src attribute.

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto — http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-src

Comment: console.log is far better than alert (if you're not using IE). It'll log objects so you can inspect them (with Firefox I prefer Firebug). For an explanation about constructor functions and prototype you can see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: Thx Quentin ... I did not knew about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick to your javascript definition, all you need to do to solve this problem is to change the attribute `onClick` on your html code to `new myFunction("...");`

```
<input type="image" src="http://..." onclick="new myFunction('Info clicked')"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling `this.temp()` on the constructor function and not on an instance of it.

You need to create an instance with `new`.

```
new myFunction('Info clicked')
```

Note that this doesn't make sense. If you want to do things when the constructor runs, you should assign the methods to the constructor and not the prototype.

Comment: What do you mean, "on the constructor"?

Comment: @Bergi — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Without `new`, `this` is not the constructor, and with `new` it's neither. So what do you mean? Calling a method of the instance from within the constructor is fine in general.